# Kendo UI WYSIWYG inline Editor toolbar is hidden when in modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, kendo-ui, modal-dialog

I have a Kendo UI Editor that I used as an inline editor just like explained in http://demos.kendoui.com/web/editor/inline-editing.html. The editor is implemnted inside bootstrap modal, but the toolbar is not showing up when I click on the content. It appears to be some kind of z-index collision between the modal and the editor. Anyway to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Try if it helps

```
$('#myModal').on('shown', function() {
    $(document).off('focusin.modal');
});
```